# Hide the bash script in jenkins console

Tags: jenkins

I have a Makefile, which has a target has **check-env**,

```
check-env:
   export password=${user_pwd}
```

when i try to execute the below Makefile target in jenkins pipeline how can i don't show this in console

```
+ make check-env
export password=
```

Tried adding **#!/bin/bash +x** at the top of the file, but still its showing this  in the console. Also how can i do for a single line so when export happens i don't want to show on the console but remaining steps i wanted to see.

Also is it the correct way of accessing env variables **${user_pwd}** or it should be **${env.user_pwd}**

Also is it possible can i test in my local before doing it in jenkins, using macos ?

Comment: If it is a shell script then "set +x" should do.

Comment: Should i add like this -> set +x export password=${user_pwd}

Comment: Yes, these needs to be different lines, one after another.

Comment: In Makefile it doesn't work @ Pankaj, we can use @ for hiding. Kindly check the answer

Comment: great, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide in terminal or in jenkins console. Or any where want to hide it

In Makefile you can add **@** infront of the line

**example**

```
 @export password=${user_pwd}
```